# Can two Derby databases run on the same host?

Tags: java, database, derby

Can two Derby databases run on the same host? I have spent a day on this, and I don't know if the problem is in my configuration or a more fundamental issue.

Comment: I would post the errors / issues that you get in order to get some better focused answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not. Have you configured your database instances to use different ports? http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/adminguide/tadminappssettingportnumbers.html might help you there.

Comment: If reconfiguring the port numbers solved your problem, then the question should be re-worded as: "Can two Derby *network servers* run on the same host?", to make it clear that this was a network server configuration question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. You can reconfigure where data gets stored (if not running entirely in-memory), and the network info (if not embedded) - either of which could be causing you issues. Without a clearer question, however, it's difficult to help more.